# OpenGraph Inline Video in Linkedin URL Shares

Tags: video, youtube, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, vimeo

I have Youtube/Vimeo videos that are embedded in a webpage and I would like those videos to be playable inline when the link to the page is shared on LinkedIn. The OG tags that are currently in use make this work for Facebook, but they are unsuccessful on LinkedIn.

Here are the OG tags that I'm using:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="url_of_my_website" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="my_website_name" />
<meta property="og:fb:app_id" content="my_app_id" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:title" content="my_page_title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="my_page_description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="my_image_url" />
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2CyV4Uu-skI" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2CyV4Uu-skI" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html" />
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://www.youtube.com/v/2CyV4Uu-skI?version=3&amp;amp;autohide=1" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.youtube.com/v/2CyV4Uu-skI?version=3&amp;amp;autohide=1" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

I know that videos are capable of playing inline as posting the direct link to the Youtube/Vimeo video displays a video preview that can be played inline.

[This is what it looks like when I share a link to my page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0kKh.png)

[This is what it looks like when I share a link to the Youtube/Vimeo video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuVfd.jpg)

I have tried using different URLs to be sure that the cached page data wasn't a problem, but that didn't help.

What have people done to have inline playing videos work on LinkedIn for their website?

Comment: Did you sort this ??

Comment: @levilucas unfortunately no, never did.

Answer (score -1):

This is easy if you use the [**LinkedIn UGC Post API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api)!  This is a three-step process: request permission to upload, upload, and then share.

**Step 1 - Get Permission to Upload**

As stated in this API...

> Creating UGC Posts with video requires uploading a video asset to get a digitalmediaAsset URN to be used in creating the UGC Post.

So, first, you need to upload the video to LinkedIn.  Taking a look at the [LinkedIn Documentation for Vector Assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api) shows that you can do this with a simple request...

```
{
  "registerUploadRequest":{
  "owner":"urn:li:organization:10000",
  ....
```

The response of of this will be an upload URL that you can upload to using `curl`.  This response will look like this...

```
{
    ...
    "uploadMechanism": {
        "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest": {
            "headers": {
                "media-type-family": "STILLIMAGE"
            },
            "uploadUrl": "https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5522AQHn46pwH96hxQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQLKRJOn_yNw6wAAAW2T0DWnRStny4dzsNVJjlF3aN4-H3ZR9Div77kKoQ&app=1983914&sync=0&v=beta&ut=1Dnjy796bpjEY1"
        }
}
```

**Step 2 - Upload the Video**

In Bash, for instance, you would upload your video with...

```
curl -i --upload-file ~/Desktop/Myimage.jpg -H 'Authorization: Bearer Redacted' "https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5522AQHn46pwH96hxQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQLKRJOn_yNw6wAAAW2T0DWnRStny4dzsNVJjlF3aN4-H3ZR9Div77kKoQ&app=1983914&sync=0&v=beta&ut=1Dnjy796bpjEY1"
```

You'll know this succeeded, because you'll get back a `201 Created` response.

**Step 3 - Share the Video**

Using the above-linked UGC Post API, set up a POST body like this and send the request to LinkedIn...

```
{
    "author": "urn:li:organization:5590506",
    ...
            "media": [
                {
                    "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5500AQG7r2u00ByWjw",
                    "status": "READY",
                    "title": {
                        "attributes": [],
                        "text": "Sample Video Create"
                    }
```

Once again, you'll know you have success if you get back a response of `201 Created`.